# What does this circuit do? Is it an infrared interface?

Tags: identification

I have the following mystery circuit:

[image]

The "LED" is a placeholder. It is very likely not an LED as it has no flattened side to discriminate anode/cathode:

[image]

The transistor is labeled "1G s(underlined) 22(vertical)". I believe this is the [BC847C](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC847_SER.pdf).

The circuit it connected to an ATMEGA169A.

Any idea what this might be doing and how it works?

Comment: I think it's a photodiode or phototransistor, and not an LED because that's looks like a really weird detection circuit, not a drive circuit. Not any detection circuit I would ever come up with but it definitely doesn't look like a drive circuit. Those devices still have anodes and cathodes though.

Comment: It's really hard to say without more context, but it does look like it could be configured to both transmit or receive IR signals (half-duplex).

Answer (score 0):

The clear thing you show in the middle is an LED.  LEDs can be used as a photodiode (light detector) as well as the normal use of emitting light.

Your circuit appears to be some kind of combined transmitter/receiver using the LED to both transmit and receive.

There's a couple of ways I can imagine it working, and which one it really is kind of depends on where the TXD and RXD lines go.  I'm not going to describe them both.

Regardless, it can transmit and receive but it can't do both at one time.  This would be called "half duplex."

Comment: Thank for the answer. RXD and TXD stand for the pins at the ATMEGA169A. Sorry if that was not clear.

I am somewhat irritated that there is no opamp in this circuit. From what I understand, using LEDs as photodiode really should not be possible without one, right?

I tried applying ground to PF0_ADC0 to get LED emission but did not get any. Neither in the visible nor on my digital camera which usually shows IR LEDs.

Comment: PF1 needs to be high or floating.  If you then ground PF0, then the LED should emit.